# How can I reload a script using react?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a script that is being load in the beginning of my page which is an external script that contains some animations. The thing is, when change my routes, my script animations are lost. I have to reload the page again to see them.

I used **react-load-script**  but can't seem to find a way.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if it will help you, as you don't give much details, but you could try to inject a script tag to reload your animation:

```
function reloadAnimation() {
  const [ head ] = document.getElementsByTagName('head');
  const script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.src = 'your_animation_script.js';
  head.appendChild(script);
}
```

And call it every time a route is changing:

```
<Route path="/" onChange={reloadAnimation} ...>
  ...
</Route>
```

Comment: wont this append multiple scripts?